# Intersecting subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two subspaces, $A$ and $B$ in ambient space $\mathbb{R}^d$, with dimensions $n$ and $m$, respectively.   Suppose further that $n<m$ and the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is nontrivial, that is $A\cap B \neq \{0\}$.  Then must it be the case that $A\cap B = A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the space $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. Let $A = \{ (x_{1}, x_{2}, 0, 0) : -\infty < x_{1} < \infty \text{ and } -\infty < x_{2} < \infty \} $ and $B = \{ (0, x_{2}, x_{3}, 0) : -\infty < x_{2} < \infty \text{, } -\infty < x_{3} < \infty \text{, and } -\infty < x_{4} < \infty \} $. $A$ is two dimensional, $B$ is three dimensional, and $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ is four dimensional. The intersection of $A$ and $B$ is $\{ (0, x_{1}, 0, 0) : -\infty < x_{1} < \infty \} $, which is one dimensional.